# Vb.net additional information Operator '-' is no define for type 'Date' and type 'integer'

Tags: vb.net

> An unhandled exception of type `System.InvalidCastExeption` occured in
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information : `Operator '-' is not defined for type 'Date'
>   and type ' integer

This is what I am trying to do

```
DataGridview1

Date |  item1 qty  |item2 qty  |item3qty
03/05| ___50____ |___50_____|__50____
03/06| ___50____ |___50_____|__50____
03/07| ___50____ |___50_____|__50____
03/08| ___50____ |___50_____|__50____
03/09| ___50____ |___50_____|__50____

Dim order as intger
Order = 20
Dim z as integer
For z = 0 To 4
 DataGridview1.Rows(item3).Cells(z).Value = DataGridview1.Rows(item3).Cells(z).Value - order
Next
```

The result must be:

```
Date    |item1 qty |item 2 qty |item3 qty |
03/05| ___50____ |___50_____|__30_____|
03/06| ___50____ |___50_____|__30_____|
03/07| ___50____ |___50_____|__30_____|
03/08| ___50____ |___50_____|__30_____|
03/09| ___50____ |___50_____|__30____|
```

Im trying to subtract the quantity of column item3 by 20 for each row date.

Comment: The error message speaks for itself. You cannot subtract an `Integer` from a `Date` using the `-` operator. Maybe if you were provide an explanation of what you're actually trying to achieve, we could suggest a way to achieve it without having to guess or make assumptions.

Comment: The fact that you have no badges indicates that you ignored the prompt to take the site tour when you registered, which is a bad idea. You should do so now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well, then update your question to acceptable standards.

Comment: E.g. if you want to subtract a number of days from the date then you can call `AddDays`.  Anything more than that, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem. That ALWAYS includes a description of exactly what you're trying to achieve, a description of exactly how you're trying to achieve it and a description of exactly what happens when you try. You got the last two, which is good, but you missed the first. It's hard for us to tell you how to write code to do what you want when you don't tell us what you want. Working it out from code that doesn't do it is not ideal.

Comment: I also just realised that you appear to be trying to modify every cell in a row rather than every cell in a column. Maybe you are trying to subtract `Integer` values after all. How would we know when you refuse to provide an explanation? Make the effort to help us help you.

Comment: So, are you saying, without actually saying, that you want to subtract 20 from all the numbers in the fourth column?  How hard is it to write "I want to subtract 20 from all the numbers in the fourth column?

Comment: In that case, you should be using the loop counter to specify the row index and then use a constant column index, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Youre so great..i got the answer through your replies,i was just confuse..Thank you for your help.appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using a variable (`item3`) whose value and declatarion are not stated. I can only assume you have defined it somewhere else and it has a value of 0.
Your loop, in its first cycle, gets DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cell(0).Value (which is a date) and try to subtract 20 from it and that gives you the error as you can't subtract an `Integer` from a `Date` with the `-` operator.
Also, you are using the iteration variable `z` to index `Cells` instead of rows. You are actually changing 5 cells of row 0 and that also would give you an error as `Cells(4)` does not exists.

You should rewrite you code as this:

```
Dim item3 as Integer = 3 'This could be a constant
Dim order as intger
Order = 20 'This also could be a constant
Dim z as integer
For z = 0 To 4
 DataGridview1.Rows(z).Cells(item3).Value = DataGridview1.Rows(z).Cells(item3).Value) - order
Next
```